# Xcode print symbol not found for my C function which used in Objective-C method body

Tags: objective-c, xcode, symbol-not-found

Xcode build prints this error .

> Undefined symbols:
>   "EGViewportDimensionMake(unsigned int,
>   unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned
>   int)", referenced from:
>         -[Renderer render] in Renderer.o ld: symbol(s) not found collect2: ld
>   returned 1 exit status

I cannot figure out what's the problem. I'm not good at classic C syntax.
These are the function source code files:

**EGViewportDimension.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

struct EGViewportDimension
{
    NSUInteger x;
    NSUInteger y;
    NSUInteger width;
    NSUInteger height;
};
typedef struct EGViewportDimension EGViewportDimension;

EGViewportDimension EGViewportDimensionMake(NSUInteger x, NSUInteger y, NSUInteger width, NSUInteger height);
```

**EGViewportDimension.m**

```
#import "EGViewportDimension.h"

EGViewportDimension EGViewportDimensionMake(NSUInteger x, NSUInteger y, NSUInteger width, NSUInteger height)
{
    EGViewportDimension dim;
    dim.x = x;
    dim.y = y;
    dim.width = width;
    dim.height = height;
    return dim;
}
```

I referenced and used this like:

**Renderer.mm**

```
#import "EGViewportDimension.h"

//.... many codes omitted.

EGViewportDimension vdim = EGViewportDimensionMake(0, 0, backingWidth, backingHeight);
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Did you make sure EGViewPortDimension.m is included in the build(or compile) folder of the target?

Comment: I checked it right now in project tree. And it's exist at here.

Targets > app3 > Compile Sources (17) > EGViewportDimention.m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by renaming Renderer.mm to Renderer.m.
It was used some C++ classes so I made it as Objective-C++ code, but there was some problem.
I removed all C++ calls and renamed it to Objective-C code.

But I still don't know what's the problem with Objective-C++ with classic C function definition.

----(edit)----

I asked this as another question, and I got an answer. See here:
[Does it prohibited calling classic C function from Objective-C++ class method body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213692/does-it-prohibited-calling-classic-c-function-from-objective-c-class-method-bod)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a compiler but a linker issue. You referenced this method from `[Renderer render]`, however the linker is unable to find it. Did you check you have included `EGViewportDimension.h` at the appropriate place (eg. Renderer.m)?

Comment: Yes, I added the code fragment of Renderer.mm to question.
I'm guessing I used some wrong C syntax. But I can't figure it out.